Mysqli Error: No index used in query/prepared statement en PHP
Tengo la siguiente clase la cual contiene funciones que permiten conectar MySql con PHP.
class.Database.php
<?php
class Database extends mysqli
{
    private $db_host     = "localhost";
    private $db_user     = "root";
    private $db_password = "123";
    private $db_database = "puntoventabd";
    private static $dbMysqli;
        
    function __construct()
    {
        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
        parent::__construct($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_password, $this->db_database);
    }
    
    public function select($query)
    {
        try
        {
            $result = $this->query($query);
            if(isset($result->num_rows))
            {
                if($result->num_rows > 0)
                {
                    $rows = $this->resultToArray($result);
                    $result->free();
                    return $rows;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e)
        {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function insert($query)
    {
        try
        {
            $this->multi_query($query);
            $insert_id = $this->insert_id;
            return $insert_id;
        }
        catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public function update($query)
    {
        try
        {
            $success = $this->query($query);
            return $success;
        }
        catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function resultToArray($result)
    {
        $rows = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }

    private function __clone(){ }
    
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if(!self::$dbMysqli)
        { 
            self::$dbMysqli = new self();
        }
        
        self::$dbMysqli->set_charset("utf8");
        self::$dbMysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
        return self::$dbMysqli;
    }  
}
?>

El problema esta cuando hago una consulta como las que muestro a continuación:
$query = "SELECT * FROM usuario";
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM usuario";
$query = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id_usuario <> 2";
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuario WHERE id_usuario > 5";

En ese tipo de consultas me marca el siguiente error:

No index used in query/prepared statement...

Pero si en la cláusula WHERE paso un parámetro funciona de maravilla. Ejemplo:
$query = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id_usuario = $id_usuario";

Estructura de la tabla usuario:
CREATE TABLE `usuario` (
  `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `contrasena` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE `usuario`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_usuario`),
  ADD KEY `usuario` (`usuario`);

ALTER TABLE `usuario`
  MODIFY `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

Por que esta pasando esto y como lo soluciono??
ACTUALIZACIÓN
Cómo nadie me quiso contestar y no es la primera vez que pasa, entonces tuve que investigar y solo encontré que quitando o modificando mysqli_report se elimina ese error y todo funciona de forma correcta.
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL ^ MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX);

No sé si esto sea la mejor solución pero como nadie me ha dado una solución y lo que encontré es lo que me ha funcionado al momento pues así lo pienso dejar.
Espero que algun experto en este tipo de errores pueda darme una solución o que me confirme que esto que encontré es lo más adecuado para este problema.

Al usar MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL se pueden evidenciar problemas de diseño en tus tablas/consultas. ¿Cuál es la estructura de la tabla?

Aparte de lo que te comenta @Sal tu método select tiene poca utilidad, no es otra cosa que un mal sustituto del método query propio de mysqli en el cual usas una práctica no recomendada para saber si una consulta arrojó filas. La propiedad num_rows depende del buffer, por lo que en algunos casos, aunque haya filas, ese método te puede engañar, diciéndote que no hubo filas. Para más detalles revisa esta respuesta donde hay una prueba basada en código de lo engañoso que puede ser num_rows. Para saber si hay filas ...

... tú puedes verificar los mismos datos, por ejemplo, resultToArray() (también inútil a mi parecer, porque solamente enmascara al método fetch) devolverá un array vacío si no hay filas y verificando si el mismo está vacío ya sabrás que no hubo filas. Para cuestiones más delicadas, como una verificación previa a una inserción para evitar duplicados, puedes hacerlo con SELECT COUNT(*)

@Sal agregue la estructura de la tabla

@A.Cedano pero no entiendo que tiene que ver la propiedad num_rows con el error que mysqli esta arrojando?? O ese error se refiere a consultas vacias

Tu tabla no tiene índices, ¿no piensas consultar la tabla por alguna(s) columna(s) en particular?, normalmente se busca por usuario.

@Sal la tabla tiene una columna como llave primaria, claro pienso consultar ya sea por id_usuario o usuario.

@Sal por el momento he agregado un índice a la tabla usuario (actualice la pregunta) pero sigue lanzando ese error unicamente con la consulta SELECT * FROM usuario

Ese mensaje se origina debido a un bug en Mysql que fue corregido en la versión 8.0.26 según este enlace. Todo lo que te comenté anteriormente se refiere a la calidad de tu código. Por otra parte, en un entorno de producción no conviene usar MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL. Esto puede ser útil en la fase de desarrollo, pero no en producción, donde además deberías evitar mostrar mensajes de error internos a los usuarios, los cuales a veces revelan información que podría ser explotada por usuarios mal intencionados.

@A.Cedano había leído en otros sitios lo que comentas de MYSQL_REPORT_ALL, entonces quiero entender que en fase de producción no se tienen que habilitar errores de MYSQL y de PHP??

No exactamente. En fase de desarrollo conviene reportar el mayor número de errores, warnings, etc, porque eso ayudará a escribir mejor el código, corrigiendo también situaciones que no son errores graves pero que afectan al rendimiento o a otros aspectos de tu programa. En cambio en fase de producción debes reportar aquellos errores que pueden ser graves o no graves pero que afectan al funcionamiento del programa, pero no mostrar los mensajes de error internos, sino mostrar mensajes personalizados que orienten al usuario final sobre lo que está haciendo mal o qué hacer en casos de error.
